# AIML User repetition

Tags: chatbot, aiml

Hello there I'm trying to make my bot detect repeat words. I have prefixed all my patterns to mainbot. This is my code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="2.0">

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT BYE</pattern>
<template>BYE</template>
</category>


<category>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<template>
 <think><set name="userinput"><star/></set></think>
                            
<condition name="userinput">
    <li><value><input index="2"/></value><srai>REPEAT <star/></srai></li>
                                            
    <li><srai>MAINBOT <star/></srai></li>
     </condition>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>REPEAT *</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="repeatcount">
    <li value="unknown"><think><set name="repeatcount">1</set></think><srai>MAINBOT <star/></srai></li>
                                                 
    <li value="1"><think><set name="repeatcount">2</set></think><star/>, <star/>, <star/>is that all you can say</li>
<li value="2"><think><set name="repeatcount">3</set></think>stop</li>
<li value="3"><think><set name="repeatcount">4</set></think>i am warning you</li>
<li value="4"><think><set name="repeatcount">5</set></think>this is last time</li>
<li value="5"><think><set name="repeatcount">6</set></think>ok 
</li>



    </condition>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>MAINBOT *</pattern>
<template><srai>REPEAT <star/></srai></template>
</category>




</aiml>
```

This works fine sometimes but sometimes wont
[Programab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6BtZ.png)

This is my main aiml file code in which i have prefixed all patterns with mainbot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="2.0">

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT HI</pattern>
<template><random>
<li>Helo</li>
<li>Heyyyyyyy</li>
<li>Hellooo</li>
<li>Hi</li>
</random></template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT HEY #</pattern>
<template><srai>HI</srai></template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT HOW ARE YOU</pattern>
<template>i'm fine! and you?</template>
</category>

<category>
        <pattern>MAINBOT WHAT IS THE DATE TODAY</pattern>
        <template>Today is <date/></template>
    </category>
        

<category>
<that>Hi</that>
<pattern>MAINBOT HI</pattern>
<template>hii ani!</template>
</category>

<category>
<that>Helo</that>
<pattern>MAINBOT HEY *</pattern>
<template>i think we have just covered greeting part of the conversation</template>
</category>

<category>
<that>Hellooo</that>
<pattern>MAINBOT HELLO #</pattern>
<template>Aww</template>
</category>

<category>
<that>Heyyyyyyy</that>
<pattern>MAINBOT HEY #</pattern>
<template>good to see you again</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT IM WELL</pattern>
<template>glad to know!</template>
</category> 

<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT IM GOOD</pattern>
<template><srai>IM WELL</srai></template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

The problem is bot responds like this all the time

[Main problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19Tk.png)

Is there anything wrong with my code? If yes then please help me to fix it. I'm using programab.

Comment: 2 immediate things that spring to mind are 1 - you are not resetting the value of  "repeatcount" back to zero if the input is not a repeat. 2 - You set "repeatcount" to 6 but do not have any action if repeatcount=6, that's why you are getting blank responses.

Comment: Thank you it's working fine now but sometimes it responses very late like it detects user repetition after repeating same word for 8th time